# How to handle returned object from function to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Suppose I have a function

```
- (NSString *)fullNameCopy {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.LastName];
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to call this function, how to assign its value to a new object, and how then to release it, avoiding memory leaks, and bad access.

Would it be like

```
NSSting *abc = [object fullNameCopy];
```

// Use it and release

```
[abc release];
```

or I should alloc abc string too ?

Update:

The point here, Can I return non-autorelease objects from a function and then release them in the calling function. As per Obj-C function naming conventions, a function name containing alloc or copy should return object assuming that calling function has the ownership.

As in above case, my function "fullNameCopy" return a non-autoreleased abject, and I want to release them in the calling function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Since the method name contains the word ‘copy’, Cocoa convention dictates that the method returns an object that is owned by the caller. Since the caller owns that object, it is responsible for releasing it. For example:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    NSString *abc = [object fullNameCopy];

    // do something with abc

    [abc release];
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `-autorelease` instead of `-release`:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    NSString *abc = [[object fullNameCopy] autorelease];

    // do something with abc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028317/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-return-data-from-function-without-leaking-memory) post

UPDATE:

```
- (NSString *)fullNameCopy {
    NSString *returnString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.LastName]; // Autorelease object.
    return returnString;
}

-(void) someFunction {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *fullName = [self fullNameCopy];

    [pool release]
}
```

Comment: Thanx pratikshabhisikar

My point is, I am using "Copy" word in my function name, so I want to return a non-autoreleased object, so the calling method hold the ownership of the returned object, and is responsible for release. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But its not in the best practices. when you make huge API's and do this stuff, the users would have to manually release and being unaware of it would cause memory leaks, finally saying your API is bad.

Comment: @prat Not true. The OP is correctly following the convention that a method whose name contains the word ‘copy’ returns an object that’s owned by the caller. If a developer is unaware of that rule, (s)he is unaware of memory management in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanx u all for ur help, Specially @pratikshabhisikar and @Bavarious.

Answer (score 0):

Like This:

```
- (NSString *)fullName {

    NSString * retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.LastName];

    return [retVal autoRelease];
}
```

Then

NSSting *abc = [object fullName];

Comment: A method whose name contains ‘copy’ returns an object that’s owned by the caller. In your answer, the method returns an object that isn’t owned by the caller

Comment: Now your answer correctly follows Cocoa naming conventions, but it’s not quite what the OP has asked.

Comment: I'm confused though. wouldn't that make the string leak?

Comment: Not if the caller (auto)releases the object. A method whose name contains ‘copy’ returns an object that’s owned by the caller. If the caller releases the object, everything’s fine. If the caller doesn’t release the object, then it’s a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

return [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstName, self.LastName]autorelease];